# Issue on invoking timeline's plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Codecanyon's plugin [Content Timeline](http://codecanyon.net/item/content-timeline-responsive-wordpress-plugin/3027163).

```
$('.read_more').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Fechar') {
        $(this).text('Saber Mais');
        $.timeline('close', "06/08/2012"); // The id "06/08/2012" is only an example.
    } else {
        $(this).text('Fechar');
    }
});
$('.t_close').remove();
```

I want to call this `$.timeline('close', id);` to close the opened element, but it is not working. I get the label changed, but the closing action is not done. Does someone know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.timelineLight').timeline('close', $(this).attr('data-id'));
```

This works.

```
$('.timelineLight').timeline({
    openTriggerClass : '.read_more',
    startItem : '15/08/2012',
    categories: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
});
$('.read_more').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Fechar') {
        $(this).text('Saber Mais');
        $('.timelineLight').timeline('close', $(this).attr('data-id'));
    } else {
        $(this).text('Fechar');
    }
});
$('.t_close').remove();
```